# ASP.NET DLL gets deleted every second build

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using a C# WebForm app. IDE is VS2019 version 16.11.24

I'm dealing with a very strange behavior:

My solution is consisted of 3 DLLS. for simplicity let call them
a.dll, b.dll and c.dll.

a.dll depends on b.dll and b.dll depends on c.dll.

The build output path for all 3 dlls is bin folder(debug and release).

The behavior I see now is whenever I do a rebuild a.dll and b.dll always get generated but c.dll
only gets generated on every second rebuild!(c.dll only gets delete on other builds)

None of my dll projects have any build events.

I wonder if this is a bug with VS or I'm doing something wrong(changed a setting somewhere).

More info: It seem I only see the strange behavior if I use Debug build. Release build always generates all 3 dlls.

[image]

Comment: Do a build with verbose MSBuild logging and see what it does.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of your Project Properties window: show us your `.csproj` files instead.

Comment: Finally... why are you using WebForms in 2023? It's been effectively obsolete since 2008...

Comment: @Dai  answer to  your last question is  the company policy and out of my hands.

Comment: are a, b and c .dll's referenced assemblies, or do  you have 3 projects in one project, and your build process "compiles" all 3 projects? Assuming a project, then you want to add the 3 dll's as references. At build time then all 3 dll's will be placed into the bin folder during build.  Of course if you placed the 3 dll's in the bin folder, then that is a REALLY bad idea, since then a clean project, or re-build can often blow out, and clean out the bin folder before a build. However, if this is NOT an application (no sln file), then you have to live this "bad" setup with 3 dll's in bin folder

Comment: @Albert D. Kallal a.dll in the main dll to thr ASP.NET project . B is bussiness layer and c is  DB layer.  B refernded by a and c is referenced by b. These are seperate projects.

Comment: @Albert D. Kallal. I think I try your suggestion of building each dll in its own project bin folder . Hopefully this will resovle the strange behavior.

Comment: @Albert D. Kalla I will update this post with my findings as soon  as I can.  Still  at this point I do believe this is likley to be a VS bug.  I have cleary defined the dll dependencies and build order. So rebuild should 1: delete them , Make c.dll , then b.dll and finally a.dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future viewer Info:

I can confirm this is a BUG with VS 2019 16.11.24.

This behavior was reported by 2 developers.

We copied the solution folder to a different machine with VS Version 2019 16.11.28
on it and all 3 dlls were generated every time with rebuild.

Comment: Please provide some reference link that confirms this is a bug.

Comment: @ Reyan Chougle. Not sure what you mean by reference link. If you mean a reference to a known bug in Microsoft library I am not aware of it.  However, based on our experience of just using a different version as a fix,  this must be a bug.

Comment: Whenever you claim something you should provide some reference links to confirm it